# Use a clipboard in react without using node

Tags: reactjs

I've been finding a solution or a plugin for clipboard. I have found the react-zeroclipboard and react-clipboard for my copy and pasting usage. Apparently, these needs nodejs for me to run it? Are there any other plugin that won't let me use node?

Thanks

Comment: What type of Clipboard plugin are you looking for? Something which copies the text to clipboard? Any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, neither of them work in node.js.  They're packaged as commonjs modules and distributed with npm, like nearly all react components.  Node.js is required to build a bundle or components using browserify or webpack.

```
# install dependencies
npm init
npm install --save react-clipboard browserify react uglify-js

# development with source maps
./node_modules/.bin/browserify -d -r react-clipboard -r react -o bundle.js

# for production
NODE_ENV=production \
  ./node_modules/.bin/browserify -r react-clipboard -r react \
| ./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs -m > bundle.min.js
```

And if you include it on the page you can do:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactClip = require('react-clipboard');
```

You can then add more dependencies as your app grows and you need more features, and maintain their versions using package.json.

---

Note: some packages also provide a standalone global build and/or publish to bower, etc. but you'll limit your options a lot if you avoid npm and browserify/webpack.

Comment: A slight improvement can be made by putting your build scripts into package.json scripts field. Putting scripts there means you don't have to reference `node_modules`, as npm loads all binaries in `node_modules/.bin/` into `$PATH`. See the npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path. That way the production script can become `browserify -r react-clipboard -r react | uglifyjs -m > bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`onCut` `onCopy` `onPaste` events](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#clipboard-events):

```
React.createClass({
    handlePaste: function(event) {
        _.each(event.clipboardData.items, function(item) {
            item.getAsString(function(string) {
                console.log('Pasted: ', string)
            })
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <input type="text" onPaste={this.handlePaste} />
        );
    }
});
```